# Implement otr.js in titanium appcelator ios?

Tags: javascript, node.js, titanium, titanium-alloy, otrs

I'm trying to create a chat application using Titanium appcelerator for iOS. For that i have implemented OTR.JS in my node js application. That works fine, But now i want to implement OTR.JS in Titanium Appcelator.

I searching modules in Titanium Appcelator to implement OTR for my application. But I can't  found any solution for this.

So can anyone clarify me, To use OTR.JS in my Titanium Appcelator Application. If there is any example, please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

The only Titanium module implementing OTR supports only Android platform: https://github.com/mnaamani/titanium_otr

However you can try using plain JavaScript implementation like this one: https://github.com/arlolra/otr